# Change element font-size to match body width (use of jquery for-loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, for-loop

I'm having problems with for-loop. My objective is to pick one element ".synopsis p" (there are more) and use it to increment its font-size by 1px each loop to make the element wider. When the width of the element ".synopsis p" matches the width of the document.body it stops and calls changeCSS() function to appends on body the css to change all the elements with ".synopsis p".

I created an codepen to ease the process https://codepen.io/alexandrebuxo/pen/eYvBJGJ

When I try to run the code it crashes.
Could someone help me?
Thanks

```js
    $(window).on("load", function () {
      $(".modal2 svg").fadeOut(700);
      $(".modal2").delay(500).fadeOut(1000);});
      

    var body_height = $("body").innerHeight();

    var sinopsis_size = parseInt($(".synopsis p").css("font-size"));
    var production_size = parseInt($(".production p").css("font-size"));

    function changeCSS() {
      $(document.body).append("<style>.synopsis{font-size:" + sinopsis_size + "px;}</style>");
    }

    for (var i = 0; parseInt($(".synopsis p").innerWidth()) < body_height; i++) {
      $(".synopsis p").css("font-size", (parseInt($(".synopsis p").css("font-size")) + 1) + "px");
      if ($(".synopsis p").innerWidth() == body_height - 1) {
        changeCSS();
      }
    }
```

```css
:root {
      --animation-time: 15s;
      --animation-time-2: 15s;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Ottoatta;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/OTTOATTACTYPE.ttf?v=1620751934");
      font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Light.ttf?v=1620808950");
      font-style: normal;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-LightItalic.ttf?v=1620825483");
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-Light.ttf?v=1620825483");
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: Obviously Extended;
      src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/Obviously-Extended-RegularItalic.ttf?v=1620825757");
      font-style: italic;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
      color: #fff;
      font-family: Helvetica;
      font-size: 200%;
    }
    #page {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      display: flex;
    }
    #page-image {
      overflow: hidden;
      white-space: nowrap;
      /*background-color: #000;*/
      background-image: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2171/2773/files/fundo3.jpg?v=1621377390");
      background-attachment: local;
      background-position: 50% 50%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      display: flex;
    }
    .pane {
      min-width: 100vw;
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      position: relative;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    /*.pane:nth-child(2) {
    }
    .pane:nth-child(3) {
    }
    .pane:nth-child(4) {
    }
    .pane:last-child {
    }*/
    .text {
      font-family: "Obviously";
      font-size: 0.5em;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .text2 {
      font-family: "Obviously Extended";
      font-size: 0.4em;
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    .italic {
      font-style: italic;
    }
    .title,
    .subtitle {
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffeb3b;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .title {
      font-size: 7.5em;
    }
    .subtitle {
      font-size: 2em;
    }
    .title-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 100vw;
      padding: 0 5vw;
    }
    .title,
    .subtitle {
      font-family: "Ottoatta";
    }
    .left {
      text-align: left;
    }
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
    .right {
      text-align: right;
    }
    .text-box {
      width: 50vw;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    .margin-left {
      margin-left: 15vw;
    }
    .modal2 {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: flex;
      z-index: 1000;
      background-color: #fff;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    .modal2 svg {
      filter: invert(1);
    }
    .vertical-text {
      transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
      left: -0px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      width: 100vh;
      height: 30vw;
      overflow: hidden;
      font-size: 100px;
      color: #ffffff;
      z-index: 1;
      font-family: "Ottoatta";
      text-shadow: 0 0 15px #ffeb3b;
    }
    .vertical-text2 {
      left: -10px;
    }
    .slide-right.delay1 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right1;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .slide-right.delay2 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right2;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .slide-right.delay3 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      animation: var(--animation-time) slide-right3;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay1 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right4;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay2 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right5;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay3 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right6;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .vertical-text2.slide-right.delay4 p {
      -moz-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      -webkit-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      -o-animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      animation: var(--animation-time-2) slide-right7;
      margin: 0;
      animation-timing-function: linear;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }
    .video {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .relative {
      position: relative;
    }
    .text-block2 {
      bottom: 10vh;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .e400 {
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    .e200 {
      font-weight: 200;
    } /*
    .production {
      font-size: 4.5em;
    }
    .manual {
      font-size: 4.5em;
    }*/
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right1 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right2 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right3 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      50% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right4 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -300%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right5 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -200%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right6 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: -100%;
      }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @-o-keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
    @keyframes slide-right7 {
      0% {
        margin-left: 300%;
      }
      33.333% {
        margin-left: 200%;
      }
      66.6666% {
        margin-left: 100%;
      }
      100% {
        margin-left: 0%;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
  <head>
    <title>AEON</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  </head>

  <div class="modal2">
    <svg
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      width="38"
      height="38"
      viewBox="0 0 38 38"
    >
      <defs>
        <linearGradient x1="8.042%" y1="0%" x2="65.682%" y2="23.865%" id="a">
          <stop stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%" />
          <stop stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".631" offset="63.146%" />
          <stop stop-color="#fff" offset="100%" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g transform="translate(1 1)">
          <path
            d="M36 18c0-9.94-8.06-18-18-18"
            id="Oval-2"
            stroke="url(#a)"
            stroke-width="2"
          >
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="rotate"
              from="0 18 18"
              to="360 18 18"
              dur="0.9s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
          </path>
          <circle fill="#fff" cx="36" cy="18" r="1">
            <animateTransform
              attributeName="transform"
              type="rotate"
              from="0 18 18"
              to="360 18 18"
              dur="0.9s"
              repeatCount="indefinite"
            />
          </circle>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="page-image">
      <div class="pane">
        <div class="vertical-text test slide-right delay1 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-text slide-right delay2 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="vertical-text slide-right delay3 synopsis">
          <p class="">Synopsis—</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text-box margin-left">
          <p class="text">
            In a fictional universe in which we become aware that we are
            destined to live our lives once more, and innumerable times more, we
            speculate about the truth that resides in the possibility of the
            infinite, making use of repetition as the great propeller of
            questions and answers.
          </p>
          <p class="text">
            This cyclically infinite realm portrays the consciousness of Aeon,
            an entity that was never born nor has ever died, who therefore
            comprises a collection of memories represented by fragments,
            suspended in eternal repetition.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems that you're adjusting all `.synopsis` elements, rather than picking one. Is it possible to build a [working demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here in your post? You might consider hard-limiting the loop just to prevent hanging our browsers.

Comment: Your Codepen doesn't seem to exactly correspond to the code given in the question. The Codepen is checking against body_height (which seems to be 0) not body_width. As @showdev has suggested, putting a working snippet actually in your question would be helpful . Also could you describe what 'crashes' means and show any errors - in the Codepen it just does nothing rather than give an error.

Comment: Just updated the post

Comment: @AHaworth just updated the post

Comment: @showdev just updated the post